# Matrix operation scheme in C++Builder 6

Tags: c++, boost, c++builder, c++builder-6

I have downloaded Boost 1.81.0, put the `boost` folder under the `Include` folder of C++Builder 6, and built a Console Wizard project.

In `pointer_traits.hpp` and `allocator_access.h`, there are multiple expression syntax errors, undefined symbol types, and the use of invalid template keywords. What about handling?

The main purpose is to realize matrix operations in C++Builder 6. I try to use open source libraries with good maintenance. We have other solutions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to use the Boost library correctly in C++Builder 6? I think it may be the way I'm using Boost is not correct.

Comment: Boost is certainly not C, why have you tagged it with [tag:c]?

Comment: *how to use boost library correctly in c++bulider* -- Is Boost even tested on C++ Builder 6?  From what I remember, g++, clang, and Visual C++ are the testbeds for boost.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Offtopic: are you aware that you are using 20 years old compiler/tool?

Comment: Don't post images of text. Post actual *text*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost requires at least C++11 (as evident by the `E2209 Unable to open include file 'type_traits'` error).  The `<type_traits>` header was first introduced in C++11, but the C++ compiler in C++Builder 6 does not support C++11 at all, only C++98.

C++Builder 6 was released in 2002. Support for C++11 (in the form of a whole new compiler) wasn't added until C++Builder XE4 in 2013 (though the "classic" C++98 compiler has had a [select few C++11 features](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B11_Features_in_the_Classic_Compiler) added in the years since).

Answer (score -1):

Add `#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB` before including `thread.hpp`.

Example:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

Then set 'Link with Dynamic RTL' and 'Link with Runtime Packages'.